# Forcing integration tests to run one at a time in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: selenium, testing, jenkins, junit, pipeline

I have a small collection of integration tests that utilize selenium in a class. The idea is that these tests run every time there is a merge to the codebase, with the merge proceeding through the pipeline and having a series of tests running against the new code.

The thing is, these selenium tests have to run one at a time. They're using the browser to log into a website, and the account will just log out if more than one person tries to log into the account at once, it'll just log out, and the test will obviously fail, so I need these tests to run one at a time. I've tried using the @NotThreadSafe annotation, doesn't seem to have changed anything, and I've searched through for some sort of switch or parameter that defines how many tests run at once with no luck. These tests are using junit 4.12.

Comment: As far as I know, scelenium tests run in serial by default. Do you log out after each tests?

Comment: How are you building?  Gradle or maven? Junit is single threaded by default.  Another option is to have the tests create fresh users so you don't need to login or logout.